# Populating a table with fields from two other tables

Tags: database, filemaker

I have two tables in Filemaker:

- `tableA` (which includes fields `idA` (e.g. a123), `date`, `price`) and
- `tableB` (which includes fields `idB` (e.g. b123), `date`, `price`).

How can I create a new table, `tableC`, with field `id`, populated with both `idA` and `idB`, (with the other fields being used for calculations on the combined data of *both* tables)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to script it (for repeating uses) or do it 'manually', if this is an ad-hoc process. Details depend on the situation, so please clarify.

Update: Sorry, I actually forgot about the question. I assume the ID fields do not overlap even across tables and you do not need to add the same record more than once, but update it instead. In such a case the simplest script would be like that:

```
Set Variable[ $self, Get( FileName ) ]
Import Records[ $self, Table A -> Table C, sync on ID, update and add new ]
Import Records[ $self, Table B -> Table C, sync on ID, update and add new ]
```

The Import Records step is managed via rather elaborate dialog, but the idea is that you import from the same file (you can just type `file:<YourFileName>` there), the format is FileMaker Pro, and then set the field mapping. Make sure to choose the *Update matching records* and *Add remaining records* options and select the ID fields as key files to sync by.

Comment: tableA and tableB are both updated in their respective layouts, and I'd like tableC to update itself, either at the click of a button, or automatically, so I think it ought to be scripted rather than "manual". Does that clarify the situation? Thanks!

Comment: What kind of script? I guess I want to somehow loop through all entries in idA and then all in idB...

Comment: it would be a filemaker script. feel free to contact me and i can provide you a sample db.

Comment: Hi @andyknas, I realise it would be a filemaker script, but would be interested to see what the few lines of code would be. Do you think you could add it to your answer?

Comment: Since no one has given an actual script (which was the requirement in my bounty) I'm just going to award the bounty to the original answerer @Mikhail - who has answered several of my filemaker questions.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a FileMaker script. It could be run as a script trigger, but then it's not going to be seamless to the user. Your best bet is to create the tables, then just run the script as needed (manually) to build Table C. If you have FileMaker Server, you could schedule this script to be run periodically to keep Table C up-to-date.

Comment: I am somewhat familiar with filemaker scripts but in this instance I am at a loss of how to construct one which does what we want!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the **select into** statement.
I'm unsure if you wish to use calculated field from TableA and TableB or if your intension was to only calculate fields from the same table?

If tableA.IdA exists also in tableB.IdA, you could join the two tables and select into.

Else, you run the statement once for each table.

[Select into statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp)

```
Select tableA.IdA, tableA.field1A, tableA.field2A, tableA.field1A * tableB.field2A
into New_Table from tableA
```

Edit: missed the part where you mentioned FileMaker.
But maybe you could script this on the db and just drop the table.